# MAC OSX, Beyond compare as Perforce's merge tool

Tags: macos, perforce, beyondcompare4

As described in the title, I want to config Beyond compare as Perforce merge tool.

reference to the following link
(http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs), I tried these steps:

1. Choose Preferences from the Edit menu.
2. Switch to the Diff tab.
3. Change the Default Diff Application option to "Other application".
4. Enter the path to BComp.exe in the Location edit.
5. Switch to the Merge tab.
6. Change the Default merge application to "Other application".
7. Enter the path to BComp.exe in the Location edit.
8. In the Arguments edit, enter: *%1 %2 %b %r*

But it can not work, anyone has successfully configured this?

```
beyond compare version: 4.0.7.

p4client version: DARWIN90X86_64/2015.1/1227227 (2015/08/27).
```

Answer (score 1):

The instructions you listed are for Beyond Compare for Windows.

To configure Beyond Compare as the diff and merge tool in Perforce on Mac:

Launch Beyond Compare, go to the Beyond Compare menu and run Install
    Command Line Tools.

Diff:

1. Go to the P4V menu and select Preferences.
2. Go to the Diff section and select Other application.
3. Location: /usr/local/bin/bcomp
4. Arguments: %1 %2

Merge

1. Go to the P4V menu and select Preferences.
2. Go to the Merge section and select Other application.
3. Location: /usr/local/bin/bcomp
4. Arguments: %1 %2 %b %r

Reference: [Using Beyond Compare with Version Control Systems under OS X](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs_osx#perforce)

Comment: Hi, I am asking how to config Beyond compare as Perforce's **merge tool**, not diff tool.

Comment: I added merge instructions to my original answer.